# Visual Studio 2010 Not Linking CSS File

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, external

I currently have a css file that I want to link in visual studio. I have included the file in my project yet it is still not working.

I am simply using css to change the body background. Here is my code:

**Css** - folder: /css/Style.css:

```
body 
{
   background-image:  url('Images/body-background.jpg');
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

**Html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
        </div>

        <div id="page-wrap">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p>Main Content</p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It all works perfectly when I put the style internally in the head it works perfectly. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the css file to your image is relative to the css file.

try

```
background-image:  url('/Images/body-background.jpg');
```

to get it from root, or

```
background-image:  url('../Images/body-background.jpg');
```

to get it relative to the css file.

Comment: Hello I tried this and its not working can any1 tell me why? I am using Asp.net MVC 2

Answer (score 0):

This will work in css file.

```
body 
{
   background-image:  url('/Images/body-background.jpg');
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```